# Dialogflow V2, Java API will not display a basic card

Tags: java, kotlin, dialogflow-es

Creating a google assistant app and building the server in Kotlin using Java servlets. I want to send a BasicCard to the user.

This code correctly sends back a simple message

```
    @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
override fun doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) {
    val json = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonGenerator(resp.writer)
    val res = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse()
    res.fulfillmentText = "Works Yah"
    json.serialize(res)
    json.flush()
}
```

This code looks like it should send a BasicCard, but gets a "Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse because of empty speech response",

Any thoughts?

```
   @Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
override fun doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) {

    val json = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance().createJsonGenerator(resp.writer)

    val text = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage()
    text.simpleResponses = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageSimpleResponses()
    text.simpleResponses.simpleResponses = mutableListOf(GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageSimpleResponse().setDisplayText( "Hello Dialogflow"))

    val card = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage()
    card.basicCard = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageBasicCard().setTitle("Hello World")

    val res = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse()
    res.fulfillmentMessages = mutableListOf<GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage>()
    res.fulfillmentMessages.add(text)
    res.fulfillmentMessages.add(card)

    json.serialize(res)
    json.flush()
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the output of the Dialogflow response in JSON form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an unexpected level of pain and an embarrassing amount of time, I did figure it out.

```
@Throws(ServletException::class, IOException::class)
override fun doPost(req: HttpServletRequest, resp: HttpServletResponse) {
    val gson = GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance()       
    val json = gson.createJsonGenerator(resp.writer)

    val text = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage()
    // platform has to be set
    text.platform = "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE"
    text.simpleResponses = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageSimpleResponses()
     //set both display text and text to speech
    val simpleText = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageSimpleResponse()
                       .setTextToSpeech("text to speech")
                       .setDisplayText("display text")
    text.simpleResponses.simpleResponses = mutableListOf(simpleText)


    val card = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessage()
    card.platform = "ACTIONS_ON_GOOGLE"
    // you must have an image and/or formatted text set on the card
    card.basicCard = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2IntentMessageBasicCard().setTitle("Hello World").setFormattedText("The Text")


    val myResponse = GoogleCloudDialogflowV2WebhookResponse()
    // text is necessary and it must be first in the list
    myResponse.fulfillmentMessages = mutableListOf(text, card)

    json.serialize(myResponse)
    json.flush()
}
```

This is the working code, But boy would it be nice if Google could release a Java API similar to the Node dialogflow API. Or at least a basic level of documentation for the existing Java JSON objects.